# How to Ensure Individual Research Papers are Treated Separately in a Vector Search Using langchain?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I'm working on a project where I want to use the ChatGPT API to analyze multiple large research papers by comparing their content. However, due to the API's token limit, I've been advised to utilize `langchain` for handling these large corpora.

To my understanding the process should be as following:

1. Split the research papers into smaller chunks.
2. Generate embeddings from these chunks.
3. Store these embeddings in a vector, possibly using Chroma.
4. Convert my comparative analysis criteria into embeddings.
5. Search the vector using cosine similarity with these embeddings.
6. Extract relevant sections based on the search results.
7. Use the extracted sections as input to ChatGPT with specific prompts for analysis.

My primary concern is ensuring that each research paper remains distinct throughout this process. I need ChatGPT to recognize and differentiate between the sources. How can I ensure that each paper is treated as its own entity/source during the vector search and analysis?

My data is currently structured in a dataframe in the following manner:

| id | subject | research_paper_text_1 | research_paper_text_2 | research_paper_text_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | covid | research paper text 1 ... | research paper text 2 ... | research paper text 3 ... |
| 2 | gut health | research paper text 1 ... | research paper text 2 ... | research paper text 3 ... |

Here is my Python code thus far:

```
import langchain
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma #pip install chromadb
from langchain.document_loaders import DataFrameLoader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings #pip install sentence_transformers


# load text data 
loader = DataFrameLoader(df, page_content_column="research_paper_text_1") #not sure how to load other documents here
documents = loader.load()


# split it into chunks
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)


# create the open-source embedding function
embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

# load it into Chroma
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function)

# query it
query = "Compare research_paper_text_1 vs text_2 vs text_3 and tell me where their test approaches differ."
docs = db.similarity_search(query)

#send relevant data to chatgpt with prompt
```

Any help to put me in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you!